# Unable to locate package libglfw3-dev

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

When I install the package libglfw3-dev on Ubuntu 14.04 there error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install libglfw3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libglfw3-dev
```

How can I resolve this problem?
What source can supply this package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This package is available [in Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libglfw3-dev).

The source package is named [`glfw3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/glfw3).

You may try to install this package from Debian manually at your own risk. It provides it [from Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libglfw3-dev).